# Storing the order of a list using localStorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have a sortable jQuery UI unordered list (UL), so that the user can click and drag items (LI) from one list to another, thus choosing the order of their journey.

How would I use localStorage to save the order of the contents of the UL, and then display this in my site footer for the duration of their journey?

Many thanks in advance. I have searched, but couldn't find any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to assign each element an identifier - position that it holds in the list.
While moving, change that value (for example you can use 'rel' for that)

Localstorage would hold something like:

```
1 - firstEl
2 - thirdEl
3 - secondEl
```

Whereas list would look like:

```
<ul>
 <li id="firstEl" rel="1">..</li>
 <li id="thirdEl" rel="2">..</li>
 <li id="secondEl" rel="3">..</li>
</ul>
```